# TableView Animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with some rows.  I want the selected cell to always be at the top most position of UITableView and the cells after selected cell should animate to bottom.

For animating to top I used this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    CGFloat height = 44.0f;  //cell height

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, height * indexPath.row, 0);

    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (indexPath.row * height) )
               animated:YES]; //set the selected cell to top
}
```

My problem is how can I animate cells after the selected cell to bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    // I will assume you have your tableView's data stored in an array: _dataArray

    [_tableView beginUpdates];

    [_dataArray insertObject:[_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:0];
    [_dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:([_dataArray count]-1)];

    [_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I want to animate rows above the selected index to top and below the selected index to bottom,

Comment: The principle is the same. You can adjust the code above to do that.